# AWS SNS for India

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

I am using the aws sns service to push/send messages for US mobile number and to do so used the below method.

a) load sns

```
$sns = new A2Sns(array(
            'key'    => 'aaaaaaaaaa',
            'secret' => 'bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb',
            'region' => 'us-east-1'
        ));
```

b) create topic

c) set topic attribute

d) create subscription

But, the same method is not working for Indian mobile number. Is it really possible? If so, what i have to for that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When this question was asked in late 2015, non-U.S. mobile numbers were not supported when sending SMS from SNS, and at the time, that was the correct answer to the original question.

As noted in the comments, this is no longer the case.

SNS [announced global SMS capabilities](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-worldwide-delivery-of-amazon-sns-messages-via-sms/) in June, 2016.

See also http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sms_supported-countries.html

---

Historical reference from the Internet Archive "Wayback Machine" captured in September, 2015 --

> SMS notifications are currently supported for phone numbers in the United States. SMS messages can be sent only from topics created in the US East (N. Virginia) region. However, you can publish messages to topics that you create in the US East (N. Virginia) region from any other region.
>
> http://web.archive.org/web/20150919111507/http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/SMSMessages.html

Comment: This is no longer true: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sms_supported-countries.html

Comment: @RobertoNovelo thank you for bringing this to my attention.  The answer now reflect the current status of the service, with the historical information captured for reference.

Answer (score 0):

We cannot use amazon SNS for non-US based mobile numbers. If you want to send the push notifications in INDIA you can hire external message API's or you can send the push notification using amazon to E-mail accounts